# Why does using 'key' as an object's key cause calling on object.key to return as null?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object, syntax

I recently made a project for free code camp that involved making a drum machine with React. I created an array of objects that had several key: 'value' pairs that held data to be used throughout the app.

The array looked like this:

```
const sounds = [
  {
    key: 'Q',
    id: 'heater-1',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'
  }, {
    key: 'W',
    id: 'heater-2',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3'
  }, {
    key: 'E',
    id: 'heater-3',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3'
  }];
```

Further into the code a button used a function to play the sound that was linked with an `<audio>` element:

```
playSound(e) {
    const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.key);
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();
  }
```

`this.props.key` was tied to the value `arr[i].key`. When the button was clicked, an error was thrown which said that the value of `const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.key);` was null.

When I changed the objects key "key" to "keyTrigger" so that the code called on `this.props.keyTrigger` which is tied to the value `arr[i].keyTrigger`, the issue was resolved and the value was properly called on so that the button worked as intended.

I simply want to better understand why this simple change in what word was used caused so much of a difference. To my understanding, Object.key is not a method (correct me if I'm wrong); is literally using the word 'key' as a name for a key the issue here?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` is not a typical prop and **only** used helping React [handle lists correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

To discourage people from using the key for other purposes, it is not available from within the component itself.

If you just want to pass a "key" then simply use another name for the prop.